# How to calculate the difference between different data frames with common column names

Tags: r

I have three data frames and trying to calculate the difference between two data frames (Df2 and Df3) conditioned by data frame 1. As explained in following example I have three data frames, Df1, Df2 and Df3 with common names.  In first step, in Df1, I want to compare the values of “standard” column with all three columns, “Das”,”Dss” and ”Tri” probably row wise and where ever any value of these columns, “Das”, “Dss” and “Tri” is higher than the “Standard” in Df1,   calculate the difference of same position in Df2 and Df3 and put the difference in a separate column.

```
Df1             
    Names   Standard    Das Dss Tri
    Aa  3   3   6   2
    Ab  4   6   4   3
    Ac  2   5   2   4
    Ad  4   3   3   8
    Ae  6   4   5   7
    Af  4   5   7   5
    Ag  2   6   8   2
    Ah  9   7   6   2

Df2         
    Names   Das Dss Tri
    Aa  4   2   5
    Ab  7   5   4
    Ac  5   7   2
    Ad  6   4   3
    Ae  5   3   5
    Af  3   2   6
    Ag  2   5   4
    Ah  4   6   3
```

Df3

```
Names   Das Dss Tri
    Aa  5   3   5
    Ab  8   5   4
    Ac  6   7   2
    Ad  6   4   7
    Ae  5   3   8
    Af  4   5   6
    Ag  1   5   4
    Ah  4   6   3
```

Final Ouput

```
Df3             
    Names   Das Dss Tri Difference
    Aa  5   3   5   -1
    Ab  8   5   4   -1
    Ac  6   7   2   -1
    Ad  6   4   7   -4
    Ae  5   3   8   -3
    Af  4   5   6   -4
    Ag  1   5   4   1
    Ah  4   6   3   0
```

Comment: @Arun yes that is true these are the situations in my data. I am trying to figure out for past whole week but I am not able to figure out. You pointed out correctly.
I was thinking that "sum" could be used if more than 1 column is greater.

Comment: Looks like you want the first which is greater than `Standard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script that takes the index of the `first biggest` value if more than 1 value is found and if no values are found, `NA` is returned.

```
df1 <- structure(list(standard = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 9), das = c(3, 
6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), dss = c(6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6), tri = c(2, 
3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 2, 2)), .Names = c("standard", "das", "dss", "tri"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(das = c(4, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4), dss = c(2, 
5, 7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6), tri = c(5,4,2,3,5,6,4,3)), .Names = c("das", "dss", "tri"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

df3 <- structure(list(das = c(5, 8, 6, 6, 5, 4, 1, 4), dss = c(3, 
     5, 7, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6), tri = c(5,4,2,7,8,6,4,3)), .Names = c("das", "dss", "tri"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

# get indices. run through every row of df1
# and get the maximum column index > standard
idx.v <- sapply( 1:nrow(df1), function(idx) {
    t <- which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1])
})

df3$result <- sapply(1:length(idx.v), function(ix) {
    col.idx <- idx.v[[ix]]
    len.idx <- length(col.idx)
    if (len.idx > 0) {
        res <- sum(df2[ix, col.idx] - df3[ix, col.idx])
    } else {
        res <- NA
    }
})

Output:

> df3
  das dss tri result
1   5   3   5     -1
2   8   5   4     -1
3   6   7   2     -1
4   6   4   7     -4
5   5   3   8     -3
6   4   5   6     -4
7   1   5   4      1
8   4   6   3     NA
```

Thanks for the chat. This is what you require.

Comment: one more silly question to you, I have these data frames in separate folders as each file represent different species. Each species has three different files representing three different conditions of the experiments. Now, If I can use this in a loop how to set the working directory for these three separate folders or there is better way to do this.

Comment: yes and thanks for you help, I thought just to put it as a separate question as someone like me might be wondering about it.

Comment: I used the code you provided but it seems that this code is not working properly. It seems that the middle column 'dss' is not being included in the calculation... could you help

Comment: for sixth row the answer should be -4 but when I performed it it gives me -1, I repeated the analysis and found that If I change the values for 'dss' those values have no effect. It seems that code either taking the 'das' or 'tri' or both but not the 'dss'... For me it is realy confusing.

Comment: it seems that I did not ask the question correctly, if there are more than one value higher then I want to add all the difference in the end.

Comment: df2$result <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(idx) {
        if (!is.na(idx.v[idx])) {
        o <- df2[idx, idx.v[idx]] - df3[idx, idx.v[idx]]
    } else {
        o <- NA
    }
})

Now, I am trying to take the difference of df2 and df3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22131/discussion-between-arun-and-maria-riaz)

Comment: I just tried your code as I spent some time to understand it but to be honest, I fail to understand it completely. But there is error that says: 
Error in which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1]) : object 'df1' not found

Comment: Not at all, Ok I post it as a new post

Comment: that is ok, Its my mistake I did not realize that things would go in this way. I am very new to R and this forum, so learning new things while annoying few people. I already told you the problem.

Comment: thank you very much for the code. It worked very well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct result, but note that the seventh value differs.  Using the max value of the three columns (an easier task) produces a result that differs in even more slots.

```
df1.w <- sapply( seq(1, nrow(df1)), 
                 function(idx) min(c(Inf, which(df1[-(1:2)][idx,] > df1[idx, 2])))
                )

df1.mat <- matrix(c(seq(1, nrow(df1)), df1.w), ncol=2)
df1.mat[is.infinite(df1.mat)] <- 1

ifelse(is.infinite(df1.w), 0, 
       df2[-1][df1.mat] - df3[-1][df1.mat]
       )

## [1] -1 -1 -1 -4 -3 -1  1  0
```

If you actually do want to use the index of the max value in df1[-(1:2)], replace the definition of `df1.w` (the `sapply` call) with this:

```
df1.w <- apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, which.max)
```

Using the rest of the code above then gives this result:

```
## [1] -1 -1 -1 -4 -3 -3  0  0
```