# Loop over all files in Directories

Tags: r, loops

This is a follow-up of the post [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112739/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-different-data-frames-with-common-column/14113113#comment19592656_14113113).

Here is a code that is give by @Arun:
This code run over files of different directories to compare the different data frames.

```
f1 <- list.files("<path1>", full.names = TRUE) 
f2 <- list.files("<path2>", full.names = TRUE) 
f3 <- list.files("<path3>", full.names = TRUE)


get_idx <- function(in_df) { 
sapply( 1:nrow(in_df), function(idx) 
which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1])) 
}

get_result <- function(idx.v, in_df2, in_df3) { 
sapply(1:length(idx.v), function(ix) { 
col.idx <- idx.v[[ix]] 
len.idx <- length(col.idx) 
if (len.idx > 0) { 
res <- sum(in_df2[ix, col.idx] - in_df3[ix, col.idx]) 
} else { 
res <- NA 
} 
}) 
}
```

then the last part is:

```
out <- lapply(1:length(f1), function(f.idx) { 
df1 <- read.table(f1[f.idx], header = T) 
df2 <- read.table(f2[f.idx], header = T) 
df3 <- read.table(f3[f.idx], header = T) 

idx.v <- get_idx(df1) 
result <- get_result(idx.v, df2, df3) 
transform(df3, result = result) 
})
```

Running this code produced an error message:

```
Error in which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1]) : object 'df1' not found
```

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Comment: This is not even close to being a question.

Comment: The question was I could not load the files properly and there was an error message that
Error in which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1]) : object 'df1' not found

Comment: I just edited in the question, now it should be possible to provide an answer.

Comment: @Arun if this is the answer, you could just answer the question :), I'll upvote it ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a very simple error. Change the line `which(df1[idx, 2:4] > df1[idx, 1]))` to `which(in_df[idx, 2:4] > in_df[idx, 1]))`